# Ligação entre Controller e outras classes no diagrama de classes

Tags: java, mvc, uml, diagrama

Estou modelando um projeto por meio do diagrama de classes UML, esse projeto está pautado no padrão MVC, de forma que em determinado método do Controller eu recebo informações, instancio um novo objeto e insiro esse novo objeto numa lista encadeada. A minha dúvida é: existe alguma associação entre o objeto que está sendo inserido na lista e o Controller no diagrama de classes? Primeiramente eu havia pensado que a associação de cada objeto da lista seria com os nós, mas por um segundo momento lembrei que eu estou instanciando os novos objetos no Controller e apenas chamando o método da lista que vai fazer ele ser inserido nessa estrutura de dados.

Segue uma simplificação da classe Controller com o método de inserir na lista:

```
public class SACMarianaController {

    public ListaEncadeada listaProdutos;

    public SACMarianaController(){
        this.listaProdutos = new ListaEncadeada();

    }

    public Produto cadastrarProduto(String nomeProduto, String tipoProduto, Date dataCadastroProduto) {
        Produto novoProduto = new Produto(tipoProduto, nomeProduto, dataCadastroProduto);

        listaProdutos.inserirFinal(novoProduto);

        return novoProduto;
    }
```